# Excluding deleted lines from diff output

Tags: diff

I have some original data that I do not want to reference, but I do want to be able to patch.  If I use diff -u on a file where I entirely replaced its contents with something else, instead of getting basically a 'delete all' plus all the new lines, I get the whole old file with '-' before each line.

We can assume the original data doesn't change for the moment.  Is there a way to get diff to make a patch without duplicating any of the original data with '-' lines, i.e., have it just describe line numbers to delete along the way, and then all the insertions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-e` option for both `diff` and `patch`, instead of `-u`.