# Exclude deleted lines in git diff

Tags: git

I have made several changes to a function and staged one of them with `git add -p`.
Before committing it I would like to check that this change actually does what it is supposed to do.

Therefore I would like to print the code exactly as it is in the staged area so that I can copy this function and test it in a separate file.

In `gitk` there would be this useful radio button where I could select *New version* instead of *Diff*.
However, I can not use gitk here because I am connected via ssh to a computer without graphical user interface.

If the change was already committed I could use `git show HEAD:myfile` (although that would print the entire file, which is far more than I am currently interested in) but I don't know how to specify the staged area instead of HEAD.

I am interested in both:

1. How can I print the staged changes with context lines but without deleted lines?
2. How can I specify the staged area in `git show` so that I can print the entire file?

---

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569575/excluding-deleted-lines-from-diff-output) but `-e` is not documented in `git diff --help` and when trying to use it I get *error: invalid option: -e*.

Of course I could commit the changes, search them in the output of `git show HEAD:myfile` and then change the commit if necessary with `git commit --amend` but I feel like there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that is called the *staging area* is also called the *index*.  Hence the staged copy of the file is also the index copy of the file.  To refer to the index copy of a particular file, use the leading-colon syntax: `:digit:filename`, e.g., `:0:myfile`:

```
git show :0:myfile
```

The index holds either 1 copy of the file, in staging slot zero, or (up to) three copies of the files, in staging slots 1, 2, and 3.  The latter occurs only during a merge, while resolving conflicts.  Since you are not in the middle of a conflicted merge, your file exists only at stage zero.  You can omit the digit and second colon to mean "staging slot zero":

```
git show :myfile
```

(Compare with `git show HEAD:myfile`, which extracts the copy of the file from the `HEAD` commit, or `git show hash:myfile`, which extracts the copy of the file from the given commit hash.  All of these work on the internal, Git-ified copies of files, in the special Git-only, read-only format for committed files—files that have been copied into the index are already in this form.)

To *diff* the `HEAD` commit against the index, use:

```
git diff --cached
```

Note that this compares *every* file in `HEAD` against *every* file in the index.  Most files in the index will already match the copy in `HEAD`, of course.  In particular, if you did:

```
git checkout master
<edit some file>
git add [options] just-one-file
```

then *every file except* the `just-one-file` file in the index / staging-area matches its counterpart in `HEAD`, so the diff will show only the one file anyway.

If there are multiple files in the index that differ from their `HEAD` counterparts, you can limit the `git diff` output further using path names:

```
git diff --cached -- myfile
```

for instance.  (This will still show any *lines* that are deleted.)

(There is a common misconception that the staging area holds only *new* files.  That's not the case—it actually holds *every* file, ready to be committed, at all times—but due to the way the staging area is described in many tutorials and due to the fact that `git diff` doesn't show you anything for *unchanged* files, it can *seem* that way at first.  To see a list of all the files in the staging area, along with information about them, use `git ls-files --stage`.  Note that this listing can be quite long!)